# extremas $\ln(x+y)- (x^2+y^2)/16$

Tags: calculus

Find max and min to $$\ln(x+y)-\frac1{16} (x^2+y^2)$$ where $2 \le x+y \le 8$ and $x,y \ge 0$.

My attempt is very clearly written in the images. But I have no teacher available, so I need feedback if the process I do this is correct.

[**See attempt here**](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/o0tyhmrgwg3fcol/AsszqqIBQj)

I find

- max ≈ 0,886294361 at (2,2)
- min ≈ 0,539720771 at (√8,0) and (0,√8).

Is my method correct? Is my answer  correct?

Comment: Is (x^2+y^2_ in teh numerator or in the denominator?

Comment: On the boundary part $b$, you go from $4x-16 = 0$ to $x = 2$ (and hence $y = 6$). That is wrong, $\frac{16}{4} = 4$, so you get $x = y = 4$ there as candidate. That changes the minimum. But apart from that mistake, the method is in principle correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is just fine. But you're off on the minimum.

Actually, this error is the result of a mere arithmetic/algebraic error in your step $(b)$:  You have $$4x−16=0 \iff x=2 \implies y = 6$$ but you should have found $$4x - 16 = 0 \iff x = 4 \implies y = 4$$  and so the extrema candidate is the point $(4, 4)$.

As a result, that changes the minimum.

Comment: Needs an UV to go w/green +1